# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 80

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

Hola gente tengo un error en mi código php, el error es cuando envió mis datos a la base de datos me lanza un error(LA LINEA 80 QUE ES DONDE ESTA EL ERROR ES LA ULTIMA LINEA)

y bueno he tratado de solucionarlo pero no le veo la solución xD, este es el codigo, muchas gracias por tomarse su tiempo :)

*ESTE ES EL ERROR Y DE NUEVO MUCHAS GRACIAS:*

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 80

```
 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "clini";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
 
<?php 
 
 $nombre = $_POST['name'];
 $identi = $_POST['ci'];

//Login
if(isset($_POST["ingre"]))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND identificacion='$identi'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if($nr==1)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Bienvenido: $nombre,$appelidoC:'); window.location='home.php' </script>";
    }else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario no existe '); window.location='index.php' </script>";
    }
}
  
 $nameC = $_POST['namec'];
 $apellidoC = $_POST['apec'];
 $nameDad = $_POST['namep'];
 $nameMom = $_POST['namem'];
 $identi = $_POST['ci'];
 $phone = $_POST['te'];
 $sex = $_POST['sexo'];
 $esCi = $_POST['statecivil'];
 $graIns = $_POST['gradoin'];
 $fechaN = $_POST['diana'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $address = $_POST['dire'];
 $contra = $_POST['pass'];
   
 if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(nameD,nombre,apellido,identificacion,correo,direccion,sexo,fechaNacimiento,
    estadoCivil,gradoInstruccion,contraseña)
    values ('$nameDad','$nameC','$apellidoC','$identi','$email','$address','$sex','$fechaN','$esCi','$graIns','$contra')";
  
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $name'); window.location='index.php'</script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Por qué inicias el bloque `<?php` después de declarar las variables de db?

Comment: faltan las concatenacion debe quedas asi con punto `ito:" . $name . "`

Answer (score 0):

Si todo eso esta dentro del mismo archivo... te falta abrir <?php al comienzo del archivo y cerrar el tag en

```
if(!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Luego en el alert te falta concatenar el $name... " . $name . "

Prueba y avisa

Comment: Ok gracias ya lo hice y se soluciono